# PHP/MySQL: A single SQL query to fetch forum name, sum total of topics, posts and the LAST POST (post id, topic id and username)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forum

Ok, so this is not a new problem to me but since sophisticated SQL queries is not among my best talents I would typically break it apart. Still, I'm pretty sure a single query is possible and this time around I feel like doing it right but I simply can't put my finger on it. The following is as far as I could go:

```
    SELECT forums.forum, forums.description, topics.forum_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM topics WHERE forum_id = forums.id) AS num_topics, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts WHERE topic_id = topics.id) AS num_posts,
    MAX(posts.id) AS last_post
    FROM forums
    LEFT JOIN topics ON topics.forum_id = forums.id
    LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.topic_id = topics.id
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = posts.author_id
```

So I select forum id, forum name, short description and forum id aqcuired from topics table because the column name is unique by default. Then I use subqueries to count the sum total of topics and posts per forum (is there any other way to do it?). And then comes the most tricky part. I can get the last post per forum (MAX(post.id)) but try as I might I can't get the topic id and name for it, as well as the post author, which I never even got close to. Doing something like (SELECT topic_id FROM posts WHERE id = last_post) is not working, of course, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your query and explanation are a bit confusing.  Why would you want the last post *per forum* if you are retrieve multiple rows per forum (one for each topic)?

Comment: Because I need to display a topic name (link) per each forum where the last post was made. Just like on any other standard forum really. That's how you typically indicate an active thread.

Answer (score 0):

This will not be quick

```
SELECT forums.
    forum, forums.description, topics.forum_id, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM topics WHERE forum_id = forums.id) AS num_topics, 
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts WHERE topic_id = topics.id) AS num_posts,
    MAX(posts.id) AS last_post,
    (SELECT topic_id FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) LAst_topic_id,
    (SELECT topic_name FROM topics WHERE id = (SELECT topic_id FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)) LAst_topic_name
FROM forums
LEFT JOIN topics ON topics.forum_id = forums.id
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.topic_id = topics.id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = posts.author_id
```

Or if the last id is not really the last id from the post tables

```
SELECT
    forum,description,forum_id,num_topics,num_posts,last_post,
    (SELECT topic_id FROM posts WHERE id = last_post) LAst_topic_id,
    (SELECT topic_name FROM topics WHERE id = (SELECT topic_id FROM posts WHERE id =  last_post)) LAst_topic_name
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            forums.forum, forums.description, topics.forum_id, 
            (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM topics WHERE forum_id = forums.id) AS num_topics, 
            (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM posts WHERE topic_id = topics.id) AS num_posts,
            MAX(posts.id) AS last_post
        FROM forums
        LEFT JOIN topics ON topics.forum_id = forums.id
        LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.topic_id = topics.id
        LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = posts.author_id) t1;
```

Comment: The problem is, the topic name is not in the 'posts' table, it's in 'topics'... so a proper relational chain has to be built like last_post_id -> topic_id -> topics.id -> topics.name../

Comment: that doesn't matter, you can combine subqueries as you need them, i changed the answer

Comment: Yes, that's what i thought too, except this: (SELECT topic_name FROM topics WHERE id = (SELECT topic_id FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)) LAst_topic_name ... is not really gonna work as it's a subquery in a subquery and is rejected by mysql... I mean, the last time I tried that it didn't work.

Comment: i can't reprooduce your problem, both qUeries should work, so please provide  a fiddle; besides doesn't work is not workable by any means

Comment: Ok, it works, but it's not doing the right thing. It just gives me the very last post regardless of forum. Hence MAX(posts.id) AS last_post there. It does the job correctly, but it needs to be further traced into the topic name. Subqueries can't do that because they are externalized from those joins which go through each forum separately. Basically, what I need is SELECT topics.id, topics.name FROM posts JOIN topics ON topics.id = posts.topic_id WHERE topics.forum_id = <forum id> ORDER BY posts.id DESC LIMIT 1, but I really don't know how to integrate it into the above query.

Comment: then use the other query which take last_post into account as i **already** wrote in the answer

Comment: that can't be  as there are no GROUP By or aggregation function, so please add a dbfiddle to show your problem, i really really can't  reproduce it.

Comment: yes this is right, there is a MAX function without GROUP BY, so you only get 1 row, but that is a problem with your query from the start and not part of my still valid answer

Comment: Ok, sorry. There was originally GROUP BY forums.id, but I decided not to include in the question to make it shorter as that was never an issue and even without it it would still return rows just duplicated so I figured that wasn't it. Yes, I added it now and it finally does what I need. Thanks a lot.